# Can A* search be simplified in an unweighted graph?

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, a-star

Here's an algorithm that is almost A* search. Essentially it's BFS with a priority queue that uses A* priority.

```
frontier <- empty priority queue
frontier.insert(start) with priority g(start)+h(start)
while frontier isn't empty
    vertex <- dequeue frontier
    for each undiscovered neighbor of vertex
        neighbor.discovered = true
        neighbor.parent = vertex
        frontier.insert(neighbor) with priority g(neighbor)+h(neighbor)
        if neighbor == goal, stop
```

This algorithm is missing the parts of A* that handle this fact: the first path found to a vertex is not necessarily the shortest path to that vertex.

It's easy to come up with examples where the missing parts are crucial... for weighted graphs. For unweighted graphs, I haven't been able to come up with any.

Is it possible that this simpler version of A* is correct for unweighted graphs?

Comment: If it uses A* priority, how can it *not* find the shortest path first?  And how do you compute g or h for an unweighted graph?

Comment: A* can find a longer path first if the heuristic function underestimates (which it normally does). There's a good example here: [link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cga/ai-course/astar.pdf)

Comment: The path cost g in an unweighted graph would just be the path length. The heuristic function h could vary; for example, say the graph represents a maze - so each vertex is an open cell on a grid - and h could be Manhattan distance.

Comment: If `h` were computed using Manhattan distance, then the distance between nodes *is* the weight.

Comment: The full A* has more, actually. It considers updating the priority of a vertex on the queue.

Comment: Think of the distance between neighboring cells in a grid as 1. Since all the edge weights are 1, it's the same as an unweighted graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not correct for an arbitrary `h` function. Here is an example. Let's assume that we have a graph with 7 vertices and the following unweighted edges: `{(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 6), (2, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7)}`. We can define `h` in the following way: `{0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0}`. The start vertex is `1`, the goal is `7.` It is easy to verify that this heuristic function is admissible. However, if we run this algorithm we will see that the path to the `6` vertex that it finds first is `(1, 2, 3, 4, 6)` because `f(4) = 3 + 0 < 2 + 2 = f(5)`, while the actual shortest path to it is `(1, 2, 5, 6)`.

Comment: Thank you, that's a solid example. Can I ask you a follow-up? The context I've been looking at is a graph that represents a maze, using Manhattan distance as the heuristic function. With a less arbitrary heuristic, do you think there is still an example out there?

Comment: @LisaTorrey What distance is used to compute the real length of the path(`g`)? Is it Euclidian or Manhattan, too?

Comment: Manhattan too, so it reflects the number of steps taken.

Comment: @LisaTorrey In this case, the heuristic function is consistent(that is h(x) <= d(x, y) + h(y) holds true for all x and y), which means that the shortest path is always found first.

Comment: So if you're right, then this algorithm could be used for maze search, and probably for a bunch of other problems as well. But there's a subtlety here - I've seen a proof that if the heuristic is consistent, then when A* _expands_ a vertex, its shortest path has been found. But I'm not absolutely sure that's true just when A* _discovers_ a vertex.

Comment: @LisaTorrey You are right, its not true that the path is the shortest when a vertex is discovered.

Comment: Yeah. That said, I haven't been able to come up with an example where a longer path to the goal is discovered first.