# A* for unweighted graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra, a-star

Does it make sense to use A* search algorithm on unweighted directed graphs for finding shortest path?

From reading http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cga/ai-course/astar.pdf seems like A* could be expensive in terms of memory, also for unweighted graphs, how would it even determine heuristic?

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051420/can-a-search-be-simplified-in-an-unweighted-graph) seems to conclude A* should not be used for unweighted graphs.

What would be the best/lease expensive algorithm to use for finding shortest path on unweighted directed graphs? Just a simple BFS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point to the full A* unless you have a useful heuristic to use it with.  That said, if your heuristic is that every node is guessed to be the same possible distance from the target, then A* search will give you the same result as BFS because you will look at every node reached by a shorter path before looking at a node reached by a longer one.

As for the best, the best algorithm that I am aware of is a BFS starting at both ends, using a hash to detect the first intersection.  That is, you mark the source and the target.  Then extend the source out to a depth of 1, then the target to a depth of 1, then the source out to a depth of 2, then the target to a depth of 2, and so on.  When you intersect, you have the shortest path out to the intersection from both directions.  So traverse the one from the source out to the intersection point, then the intersection back to the target.

This is, for example, the kind of algorithm that gets used to find who is close to you in a large social network like LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a heuristic, use A*.  If you don't, don't.

Often unweighted graphs have additional structure that can be exploited, eg. if your graph is actually a 2D grid, Jump Point Search is much faster than normal A*.  We'll need to know more about your problem domain to recommend anything further.